# android 6 - open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Tags: android

When creating a new file, I am getting the above error. This code works in Android 4.4 version . I am testing on a 6.0.1 device and getting this error. I have the write permission in the manifest file, tried to mkDirs() before creating the file, still the same issue. Here is the code snippet :

```
File newFile = new File(localFilePath);
        try {
            String abc = null;
            abc = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
            if(!newFile.exists()) {
                newFile.mkdirs();
                newFile.createNewFile();
            }
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
```

The externalStoragState comes back as 'mounted'. Storage location is /storage/emulated/0/testlocation/filename..

Answer (score 4):

You have to give Run time permission for 6.0

```
private static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_STORAGE = 1;
 private String[] storage_permissions =
            {
                    Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                    Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
            };
    if ((int) Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
                    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) && ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
                            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) && ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
                                android.app.AlertDialog.Builder builder = new android.app.AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                                builder.setMessage("To get storage access you have to allow us access to your sd card content.");
                                builder.setTitle("Storage");
                                builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(OmniSalesHubDrawerActivity.this, storage_permissions, 0);
                                        onContactsClick();
                                    }
                                });

                                builder.show();
                            } else {
                                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, storage_permissions, 0);
                                onContactsClick();
                            }
                        } else {
                            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(DrawerActivity.this,
                                    storage_permissions,
                                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_STORAGE);
                            onContactsClick();
                        }

                    }
                }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer and code snippet (very handy). You are right, Android 6.0 expects the user permission logic to be put in place for these to work. For now we decided to go back one API level down (22) so we can go ahead and release. API level 22 seem to work perfectly in Android 6 device. So what is the point of  upgrading to the latest API level (if I am not introducing any new logic in the app that depends on the new API to make it work) ? since there is backward compatibility, it is still safe to publish the App as is ? Isn't it ?

Comment: Two sides for that :
**First:**
Yes backwards compatibility is there ,i.e. it doesn’t require full support until you choose to target version 23 in your application. If you are targeting version 22 or below, your application will request all permissions at install time just as it would on any device running an OS below Marshmallow
**Second:**
Just because we can fall back on the old model, it does not mean that we can just avoid the new model by never targeting Marshmallow. A user with a Marsh. device will now have the ability to revoke dangerous permissions via the application settings

Comment: Thanks a lot @Bhumit

Comment: @kris please +1 & accept answer if it helps you to solve your issue...Thanks.